# How to make self style enumerate list?

Tags: hyperref, lists, enumerate

I would like to have a list like this:

```
a) Aha
b) Bla
Look at a) and b).
```

I write some code like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi)}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{\theenumi)}
%\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{item:1} Aha
  \item \label{item:2} Bla
\end{enumerate}
Look at~\ref{item:1} and~\ref{item:2}.
\end{document}
```

It works fine except the printed ref is not correct. I have tried the commented code, however it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides this functionality by default - specifying different `label` and `ref` components (if needed) for list items. Here's your minimal example moulded into an `enumitem` interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)},ref={\alph*)}]
  \item \label{item:1} Aha
  \item \label{item:2} Bla
\end{enumerate}
Look at~\ref{item:1} and~\ref{item:2}.
\end{document}​
```

The `label` key specifies how the enumeration will print within the list, while `ref` indicates the style of printing when using `\ref`.

Global settings is also possible via

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\alph*)},ref={\alph*)}}
```

which sets key-value pairs for `enumerate` at level `1`. See the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more details and setting possibilities.

Comment: +1: worth mentioning `\setlist` for global changes?

Comment: @cmhughes: Thanks for the suggestion; I've added it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works if the label key and the reference key are equal ;-) and the bracket is set inside the macro `theenumi`

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{item:1} Aha
  \item \label{item:2} Bla
\end{enumerate}
Look at~\ref{item:1} and~\ref{item:2}.
\end{document}
```